# Whats the best possible way to send data (PDF's) from a server to my App

Tags: swift, xcode, server, data-transfer

I wanted to ask you whats possibly the best way to send data from a drive/server to my App. I want send some PDF's which can be opened directly in my application.

I wanted to send it via SMS which isn't possible due to apples policy. (No apps can have access to SMS's) I also heard about a mail client which is kind of working but not really the solution I am looking for.

```
public class MyMain{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://______8080/test-app","______","______");

PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users");

ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

while(result.next()){
    System.out.println(result.getString(1)+ " "+result.getString(2));
}
}
```

I´ve found something like this, but I am not sure whether thats the best way

not available

Comment: The code i put in here is from java, I need something like this for Swift

Comment: First you need to implement functionality from the server side. Functionality like, You need to upload whatever file on a server and generate a Web Link/ web url. using this you can review PDF file in your browser or whatever platform. Using this url you can open PDF file in Webview in iOS app

Comment: okay thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution :

I have developed an application in iOS which uploads pdf and then show uploaded pdf. My backend developer does that just uploaded pdf on server and in respons for app he just give us the url of the uploaded file and we show the pdf in WebView.